# Setting content dispose based on url / nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, lua, content-disposition

Having nginx serving static files with url like `http://foobar.tld/<random_dir>/<file_md5sum_as_filename>` and I would like if I specify at the end of url `?f="filename.filetype"` - nginx parse that query string at the end (if is specified) and prepares new content dispose matching specified arguments and without any dynamic backend that's like impossible.

or instance `http://foobar.tld/<random_dir>/<file_md5sum_as_filename>?f="foobar.pdf"`

Can something like this be done with nginx/lua module? Does any one have any useful example or has done anything similar?

Comment: Let me rephrase your question, so as to be sure I well understood it. You want the user to download a file named `foobar.pdf` or whatever it set as the `f` parameter, served from a local file named like `<nginx_root>/random_dir/md5sum` ?

Comment: in both cases you get content from `<nginx_root>/random_dir/md5sum` but in second case where you set parameter `?f=` nginx sets content-disposition as well as specify name of file from values of parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed possible with nginx-lua; in particular, the [header_filter_by_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#header_filter_by_lua) directive.

Something like the following ought to do the trick:

```
location / {
  header_filter_by_lua '
    local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
    if not args.f then return end

    ngx.header["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" .. args.f
  ';
}
```

Comment: Yay! That's what I was looking for. 10x

Answer (score 10):

Pure Nginx configuration

```
location / {
  if ($arg_f) {
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_f";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is vanilla Nginx configuration